# Leaflet in Jupyter notebook is breaking on a Javascript error

Tags: javascript, python, jupyter-notebook, leaflet, ipywidgets

I'm trying to run this segment-geospatial model using the test script the developers wrote on their GitHub. The strange thing is, this worked yesterday, produced a map, and now when I try today, I keep running into this javascript error. This is what I have in my script:

```
#Import necessary packages 
import samgeo
import os
import torch 
import leafmap
from samgeo import SamGeo, tms_to_geotiff

m = leafmap.Map(center=[29.676840, -95.369222], zoom=19) #Create map that is centered and zoomed in
m.add_basemap("SATELLITE") #Add satellite image to map
m #Display map
```

When I run the cell, it returns this JavaScript error:

[Open Browser Console for more detailed log - Double click to close this message]
Failed to load model class 'LeafletMapModel' from module 'jupyter-leaflet'
makeError@http://localhost:8888/static/components/requirejs/require.js:168:26
onScriptError@http://localhost:8888/static/components/requirejs/require.js:1735:45

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. I tried restarting the kernel and reopening the file, as another user suggested, but that did not work. The weirdest part is it worked yesterday but not today. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I were to guess, you are using a jupyter-leaflet/ipyleaflet version intended for Notebook 6 or Notebook 7 in Notebook 7 or Notebook 6. Check your versions, try to upgrade/downgrade one or the other.